# Remove Identity Setting from all Tables which have Identity

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

Using SQL Server, to remove the is identity setting (auto increment) for a table, I have to drop and recreate a table.

Is there a way to disable the Idendity Setting for all tables with a simple script?

Comment: What is your RDMS?

Comment: Someone is trying to get an IOError

Comment: Is this a one time thing where you need to insert values into these columns? Or a permanent change?

Comment: @IOError why not providing what you have tried??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove an `IDENTITY` specification once set.

**I assume that you are using SQL SERVER:**

You have to use *dynamic SQL query* to drop all Identity Columns:

```
DECLARE @SQL as varchar(8000)

SET @SQL = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'ALTER TABLE [' + [TABLE_SCHEMA] + '].[' + [TABLE_NAME] + '] DROP COLUMN [' + [COLUMN_NAME] + ']  ; '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
ORDER BY  TABLE_NAME 


EXEC( @SQL)
```

**Note: `COLUMNPROPERTY` is starting with SQL SERVER 2008**

**UPDATE1 :**
According to your comment the following query

- loop over Tables
- Check if table contains Identity column.
- If True, It Check if table has Relations
- If False, it check if it contains Data
- If not containing Data it drop table and recreate it without Identity.

**Note:** Query contains a lot of code because generating create table script

```
    DECLARE @strSchema as varchar(50)
    DECLARE  @strName as varchar(50)
    DECLARE @strQuery as varchar(8000)

    DECLARE csrCursor Cursor For SELECT [TABLE_SCHEMA],[TABLE_NAME] FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
    ORDER BY  TABLE_NAME 

    OPEN csrCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM csrCursor INTO @strSchema,@strName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
    BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT
        name, OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 'Table'
    FROM 
        sys.foreign_keys
    WHERE 
        referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID('[' + @strSchema + '].[' + @strName + ']'))

    BEGIN

    SET  @strQuery = 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [' + @strSchema + '].[' + @strName + ']) 
    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [' + @strSchema + '].[' + @strName + '];
    '

    DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
    SELECT @table_name = @strSchema + '.' + @strName

    DECLARE 
          @object_name SYSNAME
        , @object_id INT

    SELECT 
          @object_name = '[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + ']'
        , @object_id = o.[object_id]
    FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE s.name + '.' + o.name = @table_name
        AND o.[type] = 'U'
        AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    ;WITH index_column AS 
    (
        SELECT 
              ic.[object_id]
            , ic.index_id
            , ic.is_descending_key
            , ic.is_included_column
            , c.name
        FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
        WHERE ic.[object_id] = @object_id
    ),
    fk_columns AS 
    (
         SELECT 
              k.constraint_object_id
            , cname = c.name
            , rcname = rc.name
        FROM sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id 
        JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
        WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id
    )
    SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @object_name + CHAR(13) + '(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
        SELECT CHAR(9) + ', [' + c.name + '] ' + 
            CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1
                THEN 'AS ' + cc.[definition] 
                ELSE UPPER(tp.name) + 
                    CASE WHEN tp.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary', 'text')
                           THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                         WHEN tp.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar', 'ntext')
                           THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                         WHEN tp.name IN ('datetime2', 'time2', 'datetimeoffset') 
                           THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                         WHEN tp.name = 'decimal' 
                           THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                        ELSE ''
                    END +
                    CASE WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL THEN ' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name ELSE '' END +
                    CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END +
                    CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition] ELSE '' END 

            END + CHAR(13)
        FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
        WHERE c.[object_id] = @object_id
        ORDER BY c.column_id
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + ' ')
        + ISNULL((SELECT CHAR(9) + ', CONSTRAINT [' + k.name + '] PRIMARY KEY (' + 
                        (SELECT STUFF((
                             SELECT ', [' + c.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END
                             FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
                             JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                             WHERE ic.is_included_column = 0
                                 AND ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                                 AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id     
                             FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''))
                + ')' + CHAR(13)
                FROM sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT)
                WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id 
                    AND k.[type] = 'PK'), '') + ')'  + CHAR(13)
        + ISNULL((SELECT (
            SELECT CHAR(13) +
                 'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' WITH' 
                + CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1 
                    THEN ' NOCHECK' 
                    ELSE ' CHECK' 
                  END + 
                  ' ADD CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + '] FOREIGN KEY(' 
                  + STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + k.cname + ']'
                    FROM fk_columns k
                    WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
                   + ')' +
                  ' REFERENCES [' + SCHEMA_NAME(ro.[schema_id]) + '].[' + ro.name + '] ('
                  + STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + k.rcname + ']'
                    FROM fk_columns k
                    WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
                   + ')'
                + CASE 
                    WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                    WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON DELETE SET NULL'
                    WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' 
                    ELSE '' 
                  END
                + CASE 
                    WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON UPDATE CASCADE'
                    WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET NULL'
                    WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT'  
                    ELSE '' 
                  END 
                + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + ']' + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOWAIT)
            JOIN sys.objects ro WITH (NOWAIT) ON ro.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
            WHERE fk.parent_object_id = @object_id
            FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), '')
        + ISNULL(((SELECT
             CHAR(13) + 'CREATE' + CASE WHEN i.is_unique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE' ELSE '' END 
                    + ' NONCLUSTERED INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON ' + @object_name + ' (' +
                    STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']' + CASE WHEN c.is_descending_key = 1 THEN ' DESC' ELSE ' ASC' END
                    FROM index_column c
                    WHERE c.is_included_column = 0
                        AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'  
                    + ISNULL(CHAR(13) + 'INCLUDE (' + 
                        STUFF((
                        SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']'
                        FROM index_column c
                        WHERE c.is_included_column = 1
                            AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')', '')  + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
            WHERE i.[object_id] = @object_id
                AND i.is_primary_key = 0
                AND i.[type] = 2
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ), '')

    SET @strQuery  = @strQuery + @SQL  + '
    END'

    --PRINT(@strQuery)
    EXEC (@strQuery)

    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM csrCursor INTO @strSchema,@strName


    END 

    Close csrCursor
    DEALLOCATE csrCursor
```

Query is tested under SQL Server 2016 and it works fine

Comment: Hi, thanks for the Query, however this is not working for me as there are relations between the tables and some tables are filled with data. I would need a query that checks only empty tables and if there is an identity configured to any of the column the table is supposed to be droped and recreated without the Identity setting. Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: It is not impossible. But it is complicated and need a large script coding. I cant provide it right now. You have to use dynamic query to generate a create table script. Maybe i will provide it after an hour

Comment: wow thank you so much, this is amazing,  I will test it today and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I had to dosome modification as some tables use user defined data types and the colation call throw an exception. it works not perfectly. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @IOError you cannot ask a general question and try to get a specific answer for a specific case. You have to ask another question with more details. My answer work fine on your question. In this way users will not help you.

Comment: @IOError it is not a good think to provide a additional detail every time people give you an answer and mad a hard work to help. Hope that someone else could help you

Comment: I was not aware that the fact of having UDDT matters in this case, otherwise I would have mentioend it. And I was also not aware of that fact when asking the question

Comment: In this case you have to edit your question because not all users will read comments. Or you have to ask a new question with all details. Hope you will get an answer

Comment: In the first command, in the part of the where it is advisable to use:

' COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1 '

instead of:

' WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1 '